# Возможна ли прямая работа по FTP в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Возможно ли на PhpStorm редактировать проекты прямо на стороне сервера, не закачивая их на локальный сервер?
Хочу перейти на какую-то толковую IDE, где можно это делать.

Comment: Не надо так делать. Самая отвратная практика что можно себе представить.

Answer (score 5):

1. **Так делать нельзя.**

   Нельзя ни при каких условиях залезать грязными ручонками на рабочий сервер.

   Даже если надо подправить одну строчку.

   Даже если один символ.

   НЕЛЬЗЯ.
2. PHPStorm так не умеет. Пока. Возможно, потому что это толковая IDE.

   Но если вам очень хочется — курите WebStorm 10 EAP. [Навыпрашивались](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1398).

Comment: Голое "нельзя", к сожалению, редко работает. Поэтому добавлю причины: а) если тестовая машинка не локальна, проверка изменений сильно замедляется, а значит и работа вообще, б) работа в несколько человек по такой схеме может закончиться непредсказуемо, поскольку конфликтующие изменения ничто не поймает, в) если это рабочий сервер, вы будете постоянно ронять работающий сайт, пользователи спасибо не скажут.

Answer (score 4):

Это стало возможно [в новом PhpStorm 9](http://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/261939/)

> Удаленная разработка
>
> В версии 9 добавлена одна из самых востребованных функций в истории
> PhpStorm — удаленное редактирование (Remote Edit). Открывайте
> одиночные файлы напрямую с удаленного сервера (FTP, SFTP, FTPS и т.
> д.) и редактируйте их в IDE без сохранения/загрузки в локальный
> проект.
>
> Чтобы начать редактирование файла с удаленного сервера, просто
> выберите Edit Remote File в контекстном меню или дважды щелкните файл.

Кроме все прочего появилась возможность сравнивать текущую версию файла с последней загруженной.

Есть еще видео ["Что нового в PHPStorm 9?"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrDX6B_0tzw) на английском языке, демонстрирующее использование новой возможности.

p.s. всегда делайте бэкапы, не надейтесь на "авось".

Answer (score 0):

В пхпшторм делал так: скопировал на локаль, повесил деплой по фтп на хоткей.
Как вариант примонтировать удаленную директорию как раздел(если у вас линукс), и редактировать.
С прямым доступом по фтп со штормом не работал, netbeans, точно умеет попробуйте им.

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm, как уже сказали, такого не умеет. Да и IDE такого практически не делают, это больше приоритет редакторов.
Из редакторов такое умеют PhpDesigner 8 (патный), Notepad++ с плагинами, Atom с плагинами, Komodo Edit.

Comment: Теперь умеет. Только недавно вышла новая версия. Посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: Точо, спасибо. Я еще толком не смотрел новую версию. Пока не спешу обновляться.